# Notify when the user moved every 50/100 meters iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, cllocationmanager, cllocationdistance

Hi i want to call the webservice whenever there is a location change of 50 meters(not less than this). I have tried using significant changes but it works for minimum 500 meters and startupdatelocations will call all the time. So How can i detect if the device moved 50 or 100 meters from the location.

I have used the distance filter as 50 meters as said in many stackoverflow questions. But it doesnt work before moving to 50 meters i got the location updates in device.

Here some one explained about distance filter - [iphone core location: distance filter how does it work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342558/iphone-core-location-distance-filter-how-does-it-work)

Comment: But it doesnt work. If you give distancefilter as 50 still i get the update in location before 50 m location change

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's Very Easy.

First Write in your `ViewDidload` Method To alloc CLLocationManager.

Here i set 50M distance .

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

    //there will be a warning from this line of code
    [locationManager setDelegate:self];

    //and we want it to be as accurate as possible
    //regardless of how much time/power it takes
    [locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];

    //set the amount of metres travelled before location update is made
    [locationManager setDistanceFilter:50];
    [locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    [locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

So Every 50 Meter change Device This Method is called :

```
-(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations {
    if (locations.count > 0) {
        CLLocation *location = locations.lastObject;
        User_latitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.latitude];
        User_longitude = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",location.coordinate.longitude];
        NSLog(@"latitude = %f",location.coordinate.latitude);
        NSLog(@"longitude = %f",location.coordinate.longitude);
        [self webservice_UpdateLocation];
    }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this but in device if you move less than 50m also it will give the location update. distance filter is not for detecting the 50 meter location change

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik - Do the above works? if i dont move also i m seeing some updates!